# How to read formatted input in matlab/octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I plan to read formatted .txt files with 5 columns and organized in the following manner:

```
0 1:0.007477 2:0.000000 3:1.000000 id:10002 #we = GX008-86-4444840 an = 1 asd = 0.086622
0 1:0.603738 2:0.000000 3:1.000000 id:10002 #we = GX037-06-11625428 an = 0.0031586555555558 asd = 0.0897452
0 1:0.214953 2:0.000000 3:0.000000 id:10002 #we = GX044-30-4142998 an = 0.00841930701072746 asd = 0.0999735
```

I plan on reading the content of these files into a matrix where each element will be taken as string. After I successfully read it into a matrix, I plan to use string manipulation functions in octave to remove the unnecessary like id: etc.

However, I am not able to read the file properly. I tried `textscan`,`fscanf` and other such commands etc.

For eg:

```
[sam,count]=fscanf(fid,'%d %*s %*s %*s %*s %*s',[5,inf])
```

returns `sam = [] (0x1) ???` and `count = 0`. I am trying to read the documentation on this but its very scantly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a working example using textscan. In Matlab it is working. I did not test it with Octave.

```
>> fid = fopen('test.txt')
>> A = textscan(fid,'%f 1:%f 2:%f 3:%f id:%f %*[^\n]')

A = 

  Columns 1 through 4

    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]

  Column 5

    [3x1 double]

>> A{2}

ans =

    0.0075
    0.6037
    0.2150
```

edit: to convert it into a matrix:

```
cell2mat(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fopen` and `fgetl` you can read each line of the file into a MATLAB/OCTAVE cell array.

A quick example would be

```
fid=foepn('c:\path\to\file.txt') %# open the file for reading

%#Loop through the file reading one line at a time
i=0;
while ~feof(fid)
   i=i+1;
   cellContents{i,1}=fgetl(fid);
end
```

Now each element of `cellContents` is the contents of a line in your file.